# ASP.NET MVC insert in two separate tables

Tags: c#, exception, model-view-controller, insert

Hello I am a newbie in ASP.NET MVC.

I have three classes `Login`, `User` and `TheTradersContext` as you can see below:

```
namespace SimpleUser.Models
{
    [Table("login")]
    public class Login
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]

        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }

        public string status { get; set; }

        public string salt { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace SimpleUser.Models
{
    [Table("userdata")]
    public class User
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sex { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string zipcode { get; set; }
        public string tel { get; set; }
        public string bdate { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace SimpleUser.Models
{
    public class TheTradersContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Login> loginusers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> allusers { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then i created a LoginController.cs that has a register function in which i try to pass in two different tables of my database the elements that i take from formcollection as you can see below. The problem is that in my database are passing only in the table login and not in the userdata.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(FormCollection forms){

    var db = new TheTradersContext();
    var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

    var p = forms["password"].ToString();
    String encryptPass = crypto.Compute(p);

     var newUser = db.loginusers.Create();
     var nuser = db.allusers.Create();

     newUser.email = forms["email"].ToString();
     newUser.password = encryptPass;
     newUser.status = "user";
     newUser.salt = crypto.Salt;


    //nuser.ID=Convert.ToInt32("18");
    nuser.surname = forms["lastname"].ToString();
    nuser.name = forms["firstname"].ToString();
    nuser.sex = forms["gender"].ToString();
    nuser.city = forms["city"].ToString();
    nuser.address = forms["addr"].ToString();
    nuser.zipcode =forms["zip"].ToString();
    nuser.tel = "fdgfdgf".ToString();
    nuser.country = forms["country"].ToString();
    nuser.bdate ="dsafdsaf".ToString();

    try
    {
       db.loginusers.Add(newUser);

      db.SaveChanges();
        var useri = db.loginusers.Single(u => u.email == newUser.email);
        if (useri == null) {
            throw new Exception();
        }


        nuser.ID = Convert.ToInt32(useri.ID);
        db.allusers.Add(nuser);

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "This username is in use");
    }

    return View();
}
```

My table in database has exactly the same names of the fields on user.

Of course I tried to exclude the code that has to do with the login and pass only the values of the userdata in database but i saw the exception : `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException`.

I have tried a lot of things until now... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your code it seems that there is a relation 1 to many between Login and User, each login has 1 or more user ( i figured this out since you were trying to put `nuser.ID = Convert.ToInt32(useri.ID);)`

in your class User put a navigational property called `public Login Login{get; set;}`

and the User class should has a primary key let us say ( UserId) unless you marked ID as primary key then your User table is a weak entity.
and mark the ForeignKey attribute for the new property Login as ForeignKey("ID")

after doing this, then easily you can do the following

```
var login=new Login();
// fill out the login data
db.loginusers.Add(login)

db.allusers.Add(new User(){
   surname = forms["lastname"].ToString(),
   name = forms["firstname"].ToString(),
   sex = forms["gender"].ToString(),
   city = forms["city"].ToString(),
   address = forms["addr"].ToString(),
   zipcode =forms["zip"].ToString(),
   tel = "fdgfdgf".ToString(),
   country = forms["country"].ToString(),
   bdate ="dsafdsaf".ToString(),
   Login=login 
});

db.SaveChanges();
```

hope that his will help you

note: your classes design can be improved and normalized to reflect the database relationship

Comment: Thank you very much!! That worked for me... The relation between the two tables was missing and i didnt know i had to declare it!!